# Make non recursive request with QueryBuilder of Adobe Experience Manager

Tags: adobe, aem

I would like to use the querybuilder of Adobe Experience Manager to request all direct child of a node.

At the moment I tryied `bin/querybuilder.json?path=/&p.limit=10`. How can I make this request non recursive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **path.flat** property to specify immediate child only.

```
/bin/querybuilder.json?path=/&path.flat=true&p.limit=10
```

Comment: Thanks, where can I find à documentation about that?

Comment: I have used this property in one of my project. Though i find this guide: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html